# Files saved on external drive with Ubuntu 14 have different permissions when displayed with Ubuntu 16

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, sudo, external-hdd, su

I saved my data on an external drive using a Ubuntu 14 machine. In that Ubuntu 14 machine, I can see in the following:

```
david@david-Toshiba:/media/david$ pwd
/media/david
david@david-Toshiba:/media/david$ ls -lrth
total 12K
drwx------ 1 david david 12K Jun 23 19:25 TOSHIBA EXT
```

Files and folders inside `TOSHIBA EXT` (the external drive) are seen in black/blue as usual:

[image]

However, when plugging this external drive in a Ubuntu 16 machine, I see:

```
david@david:/media/david$ pwd
/media/david
david@david:/media/david$ ls -lrth
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 1 david david 12K Jun 23 20:25 TOSHIBA EXT
```

And I no longer see the files/folders in black and green:

[image]

Why I cannot see the files/folders in the same way as in the Ubuntu 14 machine?

Comment: Regarding the permissions: Your mount options are the same on both systems? and an hopefully stupid q: the name as EXT in it. From external? Or ext as in the filesystem? If not the latter... is it NTFS? :P Regarding colors: that will be a different alias to the command  "ls" or a different color scheme for "ls". Those can differ too.

Comment: @Rinzwind 1) I just plug in the external drive on both Ubuntu 14 and 16 systems, so the default mounting options might being used. 2) `TOSHIBA EXT` is just the name of the external hard drive. 3) The `ls` alias is the same in both systems.